# Script to save the output in event log message

Tags: powershell

I have one script in which I am creating a hashtable to fetch account details from 3 active directory groups. It worked fine and when i called the `$hash` .. I am getting exact output. However, when I tried to put the same output in event log msg.. the log msg looked like this

> System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

```
$hash = [ordered]@{
    Enterpriseadmin = get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'cn=enterprise Admins,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net' -properties name, members | select name, @{n=’Members’; e= { ( $_.members | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} | Sort-Object -Property Name 
    Schemaadmin = get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'cn=schema Admins,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net' -properties name, members | select name, @{n=’Members’; e= { ( $_.members | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} | Sort-Object -Property Name
    DomainAdmin = get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'cn=domain Admins,cn=users,dc=abc,dc=net' -properties name, members | select name, @{n=’Members’; e= { ( $_.members | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} | Sort-Object -Property Name
}
```

i tried to save the hashtable output to a variable and then use it in msg like $msg = $hash but same output on eventlog message.

```
New-eventlog -logname Application -Source "ascript"
Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "aScript" -EventId 123 -EntryType Information -Message $hash
```

Am I missing something here? How to convert this message into output?

Comment: `$hash` is a complex object. Powershell will call the `ToString()` method of the object in order to display it. THat will only show the type that you see, PowerShell cannot predict outside of that what you want to see / how it is rendered. You need to tell it how to do that. What is your expected output look like?

Comment: Name Value
__   __ 
Enterpriseadmin @{name=Enterpise admins; Members=} :- like this in a  tabular format with all three groups which i have specified in my script!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
i have figured  out how to post the output to eventlog message
$body = $hash.getenumerator() | Format-table | out-string
Then, by just putting $body after -message in write-eventlog command.. it logs the output to event log message.